# Subprocess - Too many open Files in subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, error-handling, subprocess

On my system(using python3.6.9) I got the Too many open Files Error.

I got the error while executing a subprocess in python.

Traceback:

```
File "/opt/KIDICAP/docengine/Objects/Watcher.py", line 99, in watch, self.check_ulimit()
File "/opt/KIDICAP/docengine/Objects/Watcher.py", line 469, in check_ulimit
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__    restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1254, in _execute_child    errpipe_read, errpipe_write = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

I tried to look it up but permanently setting the ulimit didn't work.

I even build a function, that sets the ulimit before executing a subprocess.

```
        process = subprocess.Popen(comand1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.stdout.readlines()
        process.stdout.close()
        process.terminate()
        # print(output)

        # logger.info(comand2)
        process = subprocess.Popen(comand2, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.stdout.readlines()
        process.stdout.close()
        process.terminate()
        # print(output)

        # logger.info(comand3)
        process = subprocess.Popen(comand3, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.stdout.readlines()
        process.stdout.close()
        process.terminate()
```

Comment: Please let us know, what exactly your question is. Do you want to know how to find the cause of the "too many open files" error or how to increase the limit? (I don't know your application, of course, but in general the limit makes sense and should not be increased except for very special situations.)

Comment: I wanted to make a post with that error. And to anwser it my self. Because i searched for a long time until i found my own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the right solution on the Internet.

The solution for me was to edit the fs.file max
(/proc/sys/fs/file-max)

I put the value in the file on 1000000.

and to edit the bash.bashrc file to increase the ulimit in every session opened.

/etc/bash.bashrc

There i added:

```
ulimit -n 1000000
ulimit -s unlimited
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to find out what's holding all the files open? Do you also have 1000000 hung processes?

Comment: Yes would be better. I run the functions in threading. Every thread opens 3 subprocesses. I use exiftool to work with pdf files. And i start 15 processes(one process handels 10 files sequenntially) at once to compress the files. Sometimes there are more then 100000 pdf documents to be handled. I haven't found a solution to close files from exiftool.